# Button not clickable consistently in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to click a button in selenium java code and it is not clicking all the time. Apparently this is pretty common issue.

I tried below few solutions:

HTML Code :

```
<button class="btn btn--action btn--border-white btn--my__calculate" style="display: inline-block;">Final Figure</button>
```

Solution 1:

```
WebElement btnWorkout = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn--my__calculate"));

        if (btnWorkout.isDisplayed() && btnWorkout.isEnabled()) {
            btnWorkout.click();
        }
```

Solution 2 :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
        WebElement btnWorkout = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".btn--my__calculate")));
        btnWorkout.click();
```

Solution 3:

```
WebElement btnWorkout = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn--my__calculate"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", btnWorkout);
```

None of them worked for me.

Other strange thing is above step passes without an error and  button doesn't click as expected

Comment: provide HTML code of button

Comment: have you tried Thread.sleep? I mean just to confirm that is something that is taking time to load. On some cases had to use this "dirty" solution. Another that sometimes work is "driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("

Comment: Try with clicking twice or try actions click. I prefer this workaround whenever I face this kinda issue.

Comment: @Somber Added `HTML ` code to the question

Comment: @Breaks Software Is there difference behavior when come to `Thread.sleep(); ` when running IDE and command-line. Because when apply `Thread.sleep() ` it works most of the time in IDE but not command-line.

Answer (score 1):

Induce `WebDriverWait` And Following `Xapth`.
Try following options.

**Option1:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20);      
WebElement btnWorkout=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn--action btn--border-white btn--my__calculate'][text()='Final Figure']")));
btnWorkout.click();
```

**Option2:** Use `Action` class

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20);      
WebElement btnWorkout=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn--action btn--border-white btn--my__calculate'][text()='Final Figure']")));
Actions action=new Actions(webDriver);
action.moveToElement(btnWorkout).click().build().perform();
```

**Option3:** Use `JavaScript Executor`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20);      
WebElement btnWorkout=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn--action btn--border-white btn--my__calculate'][text()='Final Figure']")));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", btnWorkout);
```

Comment: I tried all above options and still failing intermittently. Apparently `javascript ` is better. The other thing I noticed was, when it's failing cannot even click the button manually in the opened browser.

Answer (score 0):

Curious that the `executeScript()` option didn't work for you.  Keep using your WebDriverWait from option 2, but instead of the `click()` method, try using Action Chains.  I'm not sure how to write this in Java, but it'll be something like this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.move_to_element(btnWorkout).click(btnWorkout).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have another hidden element with same CSS (class). You can try capture the element by *linkText* or *partialLinkText* like this:

```
WebElement btnWorkout = webDriver.findElement(By.linkText("Final Figure"));
```